# Передача переменной в контроллер через routes.php

Tags: php, laravel, маршрутизация

Подскажите, как в ларавель передать переменную через роут?

```
Route::post('/addCat', 'addOperationController@addCategory');
```

Вот вызов метода контроллера. Нужно передать переменную в данный метод

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменные в контроллер через роуты передаются с помощью параметров ([см. документацию](http://laravel.su/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters)), которые указываются в фигурных скобках

```
Route::get('/addCat/{cat_name}', 'addOperationController@addCategory');
```

Сам же метод `addCategory` должен иметь вид:

```
public function addCategory($cat_name)
{
    // при наборе адреса site.ru/addCat/test переменная $cat_name 
    // примет значение test
}
```

Если Вы передаете значение через форму POST методом по роуту

```
Route::get('/addCat', 'addOperationController@addCategory');
```

то Ваш контроллер должен выглядеть так:

```
public function addCategory(Request $request)
{
    // Здесь поле с именем cat_name можно будет получить так:
    // $request->cat_name
}
```

[Вот](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/requests) ссылка на документацию по теме.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, если честно. А если мне надо передать через post? Так же передавать?

Comment: @Андрей, да, только вместо get пишите post.

Comment: А как определить cat_name?

Comment: @Андрей, в каком смысле определить?

Comment: Ну мы же передаём cat_name. Мне нужно, чтобы в нём хранилось значение из $_POST['categoryName']. Либо я вас не так понял)

Comment: @Андрей, возможно, это я не совсем понял вопрос. Я обновил свой ответ, посмотрите, скорее всего это то, что Вам нужно.

Comment: Да, это то, что нужно. Спасибо. В Yii как-то полегче было с этим.